# How do I put a SQLAlchemy label on the result of an arithmetic expression?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I translate something like this into SQLAlchemy?

```
select x - y as difference...
```

I know how to do:

```
x.label('foo')
```

...but I'm not sure where to put the ".label()" method call below:

```
select ([table.c.x - table.c.y], ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ColumnElement` method is just a helper; [label()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.label) can be used following way:

```
select([sql.expression.label('foo', table.c.x - table.c.y), ...])
```