# Sqlalchemy: Get some columns aliased

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a question that I'm sure it's very quick to answer, but I haven't been able to find it googling...

I have a class Product defined with declarative SqlAlchemy:

```
class Product(declarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "products"
    _brand = Column("brand", Unicode(128))
    _series = Column("series", String(128))
    _price = Column("price", Float)
    _description = Column("description", UnicodeText)

    _manufacturerId = Column("manufacturer_id", Integer, ForeignKey("manufacturers.id"), key="manufacturerId")
    _manufacturer = relationship("Manufacturer",
        uselist=False,
         backref=backref("_products", collection_class=set)
         )
```

And a a certain point, I want to get some columns of all the Products, such as _brand and _manufacturerId, but instead of retrieving it named _manufacturerId I want it called _manufacturer (mainly to "hide" the relationship thing).

I don't know how to do that... It would be something like:

```
session.query(Product.Product._brand, Product.Product._manufacturerId as "_manufacturer").all()
```

I'm pretty sure that is doable, but I don't know how (using sqlalchemy 0.6.6, just in case it's relevant)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually... I think "label" may work.

[How do I put a SQLAlchemy label on the result of an arithmetic expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370077/how-do-i-put-a-sqlalchemy-label-on-the-result-of-an-arithmetic-expression)

If it does, I'll detail it here

Comment: yep, it works...
session.query(MyClass.name_sample.label('name'))